# flutter app name mismatch with ios bundle name

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

i am trying to set my app name as "Name Example" but it shown like "NameExample" and remove the white spaces

Answer (score 0):

apple shrink app name on small devices

Comment: Are you further describing the problem, or presenting this as an answer? If this is an answer, you need to [edit] to add more information.